# All attributs save default

Tags: magento2

When I create a configurable product, sometimes it is saved with all attributes by default and other with their attributes. I put an example:

I have an attribute set "Example1" and this have custom attributes "Attribute1" and "Attribute2". Also I have attribute set "Example2" and this have the custom attributes "Attribute2", "Attribute3" and "Example4".
If I create one product with attribute set "Example1" sometimes save values for "Attribute1" and "Attribute2" and other time it save values for "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3" and "Attribute4".

How and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Im not sure what You mean. If you create product with Attributeset Example1 there is no chance for display Attribute not assigned for attribute set. Have you connected any simple products for configurable? All are with same attribute set?

Comment: It is difficult of explain. For example I have 15 custom attributes and I have a custom attribute set with 5 attributes. I create a configurable product with this attribute set and I save the 5 attributes but sometimes save the 5 attributes and other times save the 15 attributes with default value in the other 10

Comment: Can you show it on screenshots?